# Loop through 2 grouped object lists & add them in an observable collection C#

Tags: c#, object, listview, xamarin.forms

I have these two grouped object lists which I grouped like this:

```
var q = it
   .AsQueryable()
   .GroupBy(x => x.date)
   .Select(g => new
   {
      Date = g.Key,
      Details = g.Select(x => new
         {
            Name = x.name,
            Price = x.price,
            Trans = x.trans,
         })
         .ToList()
   })
   .ToList();

var q4 = t
   .AsQueryable()
   .GroupBy(x => x.date)
   .Select(g => new
   {
      Date = g.Key,
      Details = g.Select(x => new
         {
            Location = x.location,
            Points = x.points,
            Pos = x.position,
            Time = x.time,
            Discount = x._discount,
            Totals = x._total,
            Trans = x.trans,
            Ref = x.refer
         })
         .ToList()
   });
```

What I want to do is looped through these lists and add their respective contents together in a new observable collection, like this:

```
Transactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>();
Transactions.Add(new Transaction
{
   Details = "Date: " + obj.Date,
   TransDet = "Time: " + k.Time + " | Reference: " + k.Ref(etc),
   ItemDet = obj.Name,
   obj.Price,
   obj.Trans,
   Isvisible = false
});
```

The two lists use the Date as the common factor that links them - is there a way to loop through both of them and put their contents into this new observable collection underneath the key date?

Thank you!

Comment: Why have you tagged objective C?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `AsQueryable`? Is that really necessary?

Comment: Wouldn't let me tag object oriented programming sorry about that! And yes it is!

Comment: Don't just pick random tags then, objective C is a different language entirely. And I would put money down that `AsQueryable` isn't needed here.

Comment: Yes I fixed it, and I've tried removing it just now and you were right it wasn't needed. - Sorry I'm new to programming, still learning!